# JavaFX Simulating Carnot Engine

Tags: javafx, simulation, physics

I am looking for some answers about building, somehow, complex animation with JavaFX.
I am trying to build a simple Carnot Engine animation with a piston moving etc.
Something similar to [this one](http://galileoandeinstein.physics.virginia.edu/more_stuff/flashlets/carnot.htm).

What I need to one is what would be the best way to start writing such simulation. 
For now I am familiar with 3 types of simulation in FX and hence I think that the best choice would be Timeline Simulation in my case.

But still I am not quite sure how to start. Should I put different bricks like rectanglagles, paths, circles on the pane without even touching the simulation and try to put the life in it or maybe that approach is complete misunderstanding ? That's the question I am looking forward to get some answers or at least hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with a physics engine class and just have textual output.

Get the coordinates of each critical point like connections and pivots in the drawing and calculate, with real physics, where it should be in the next 1/60 th of a second.  Output these positions to the console along with heat variables etc.  Make sure it's right, then fill in with real shapes and animate. Javafx sort of uses a 60 frames/sec standard.

If the drawing is 2d and the simulation is 3d (real world) physics you might have some trouble converting between the two.  For bonus points you can do a 3d simulation.

Comment: Yeah, that's a nice suggestion. Following that I am preparing myself now some theoretical background and after I end up with the layer capable of calculating carnot-cycle related stuff I will start working with animation.

However my concerns in the question are not for physics but for animation itself. I would like to get some hints of important checkpoints to remember when designing simulation. 

For instance whether to animate each component of the engine independently or with other ones ? What should I use to control animation ? Current position of the piston, time ?

Comment: [This will get you started](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/animations/jfxpub-animations.htm)  Ask a new question for specific animation problems.  This question was probably borderline OT for this board.

Answer (score 1):

Well ... I also am interested in simulators and gaming when it comes to Javafx

I created a Cloth simulator a couple months back, and while not perfect it was my first ground up simulator.

Troubles you can look forward to:

Updating the UI, all nodes must be updated on the FXthread
Running your updates without impeding performance of the Scene

AnimationTimer is an okay at best solution. Using standard animations create a heap of code.

My solution was to create a LoopService (ScheduledService) running every 16ms
(60fps roughly) This alone almost doubled my performance vs AnimationTimer.

The nice part about the LoopService is that you can have code run outside of the fxthread, and onSucceeded update the UI without having additional Listeners etc..

Here is a video on youtube of the end result: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uRsCcpbsdsg
(For some reason that vid was uploaded to an older account)

You can see the progression here on my actual youtube page:
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCxCaGZeistOC2J_rBF8JbWQ

My math is far from perfect, and it still need a lot of refinement, but I covered the difficult part of updating the UI.
In the Source code, I call the service by a different name, but the foundation is the same.

Source code for the Cloth is here: https://github.com/Birdasaur/FXyz
in the Tests folder you should find a runnable sample.

Hope it helps!

Here is an updated version of that service:

```
/**
 * Simple Looping Service. Useful for games, Simulations, or other items that require a running "Loop".
 *
 * @author Jason Pollastrini aka jdub1581
 */
public abstract class AbstractLoopService extends ScheduledService<Void>{
    private final long ONE_NANO = 1_000_000_000L;
    private final double ONE_NANO_INV = 1f / 1_000_000_000L;

    private long startTime, previousTime;
    private double frameRate, deltaTime;

    private final LoopThreadFactory tf = new LoopThreadFactory();    
    private final ExecutorService cachedExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(tf);


    protected AbstractLoopService() {
        this.setPeriod(Duration.millis(16.667)); // eqiv to 60 fps
        this.setExecutor(cachedExecutor);
    }


    protected final double getTimeElapsed() {
        return getCurrentTime() * ONE_NANO_INV;
    }

    protected final long getCurrentTime() {
        return System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    }

    protected final double getFrameRate() {
        return frameRate;
    }

    protected final double getDeltaTime() {
        return deltaTime;
    }

    private void updateTimer() {
        deltaTime = (getCurrentTime() - previousTime) * (1.0f / ONE_NANO);
        frameRate = 1.0f / deltaTime;
        previousTime = getCurrentTime();

    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        if (startTime <= 0) {
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() {
        super.reset();
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        previousTime = getCurrentTime();
    }

    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {
        return new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                updateTimer();
                // perform needed background tasks here ..
                runInBackground();

                return null;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void succeeded() {
        super.succeeded();
        // Setup to handle Actions for UI here     
        runOnFXThread();
    }

    @Override
    protected void failed() {
        getException().printStackTrace(System.err);

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ElapsedTime: " + getCurrentTime() + "\nTime in seconds: " + getTimeElapsed()
                + "\nFrame Rate: " + getFrameRate()
                + "\nDeltaTime: " + getDeltaTime();
    }

    /*==========================================================================
     *      Methods for access
     */

    protected abstract void runOnFXThread();
    protected abstract void runInBackground();

    /*==========================================================================

     */
    private final class LoopThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {

        public LoopThreadFactory() {
        }

        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            Thread t = new Thread(r, "NanoTimerThread");
            t.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY + 1);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t;
        }

    }

}
```